# Конфликт между ajax фильтром статей и contact form 7 в wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ajax, contact-form7

Всем привет! В wordpress у меня есть ajax фильтр статей, который всплывает при загрузке страницы. Кроме этого есть форма которая была собрана в Contact form 7. Так вот... если я подключаю
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.... то это мешает отправке формы( форма не видит введенных в нее данных), но при этом фильтр работает отменно. Если я использую такое подключение, то все на оборот http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.... форма работает , фильтр не появляется.
Я пробовал подключить просто как файл , но не помогло. Подскажите, как исправить этот конфликт?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Такое впечатление что у вас проблемы с настройкой https на сайте. И идет микс контент. Приведите ваши запросы или к http или к https. Без ссылки на сайт с проблемой точнее будет сложно ответить

Comment: Спасибо зпа ответ. Если честно я первый раз с этим сталкиваюсь. Как можно привести все запросы к одному протоколу, можете подсказать? https://site-by-side.ru/

Comment: Не нужно подключать свою библиотеку с ajax jQuery, так как у WordPress уже имеется jQuery под капотом и аякс вполне будет работать без этого подключения. Если фильтр не появляется или не работает, то должны возникнуть определенные ошибки, которые можно было бы добавить в сам вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае была проблема не внимательности. Был подключен js файл , который мешал нормальной работе формы. Всем спасибо за помощь!